# SSL certificate fail apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I have setup a certificate on Apache server. When I access my site's https pages, I see the certificate flashing (in FireFox's url tab) and disappearing immediately.

The browser stays in the same windows (https) but now certificate info is not displayed and the connection is not encrypted.

Can anyone recommend on how I can even start checking what is wrong ?
(Certificate fail ? Bad config ?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.sslshopper.com/article-stop-the-page-contains-secure-and-nonsecure-items-warning.html for information on how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not a server issue.

Apparently the site was serving scripts for an http address.

FYI for everyone having same problem.